# Jasper Report plugin in Grails 3.1.8

Tags: grails, jasper-reports, grails-plugin

Generate  PDF file using jasper report in Grails 3.1.8 . But when I
    add  dependencies some error is occurred. I can't adding any jasper report  dependencies 
    in Grails 3.1.8. Please help me or any idea to use jasper report plugin in grails 3.1.8.I already used

```
       (1)
       compile "org.grails.plugins:jasper:1.11.0" 
       (2)
       compile 'com.lowagie:itext:2.1.7.js2'
       compile 'net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:6.2.1'
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @Dave Jarvis Error |
Error initializing classpath: Could not find org.grails.plugins:jasper:1.11.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin org.grails.plugins:jasper:1.11.0 is not grails 3 compatible. It is only up to Grails 2.x
There is a plugin for Grails 3 version here.https://grails.org/plugins.html#plugin/grails-jasper.

In other hand, you could run `grails dependency-report` for seeing what it is happening. It seems that there is a conflict between dependencies. But as I said, that plugin probably won't work with your project.

Comment: Is there any jasper report plugin for grails 3.1.8 ?

Comment: the link in the answer is for grails 3

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I fixed it by downloading the jasper report jar and kept it in a folder named lib, then showed the path in dependencies like this.

```
compile files('lib/jasperreports-5.5.0.jar')
```